# Нужна помощь новичку в python!

Tags: python

Нужно поменять местами слова в одном или нескольких предложениях. Пример: "Hello world! Python very good language."
вывод - "world Hello! language good very Python.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inp = input()
s = inp.split('!')
for i in s:
    print(' '.join(reversed(i.split(' '))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы перевернуть строку, надо её разбить по пробелу и воспользоваться `slice`-ингом `::-1` внутри квадратных скобок:

```
s = 'Hello world!'.split()
print(' '.join(s[::-1]))
```

Перед этой операцией надо получить несколько предложений из одной строки. Тогда вам понадобится разбиение по точке/вопросительному знаку/восклицательному знаку.